# Is there a way to connect azure synapse studio to bitbucket repo?

Tags: git, azure, bitbucket, azure-synapse

Is there a way to connect azure synapse studio to bitbucket repo ?

Comment: Maybe checkout docs before asking here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#connect-to-a-git-repository

Comment: @Saihaj, I checked the docs already. I couldn't find a way to connect bitbucket in docs.  By the way, I'm speaking about azure synapse not azure data factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As of today, Azure Synapse Studio doesn't support bitbucket.

As per the product team response; `Bitbucket is on our roadmap`. I will update this answer once it's available.

Regarding service general availability, I would suggest to keep an eye on [Azure updates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?tag=azure-synapse-analytics).

Azure updates provide information about important Azure product updates, roadmap, and announcements

> Azure Synapse Studio allows you to associate your workspace with a `Git repository`, `Azure DevOps`, or `GitHub`.

**Reference:** [Source control in Azure Synapse Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/source-control)